# Setting up Oro commerce via Vagrant

Tags: php, vagrant, symfony4, orocommerce

Facing issues while setting up Vagrant for oro commerce.

```
default:   Problem 1
default:     - ocramius/package-versions is locked to version 1.5.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
default:     - ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
default:   Problem 2
default:     - robloach/component-installer is locked to version 0.2.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
default:     - robloach/component-installer 0.2.3 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
default:   Problem 3
default:     - ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
default:     - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.1.1 requires ocramius/package-versions ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by ocramius/package-versions[1.5.1].
default:     - ocramius/proxy-manager is locked to version 2.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Even though, the vagrant up, says that the the Oro commerce application is successfully installed, I do not see anything on the custom port number http://localhost:8082

Answer (score 1):

The issue happens because your vagrant image uses the Composer v2, which is installed by default now. But OroCommerce is not compatible with it yet. Version 1.* should be used instead.

You can upgrade to the OroCommerce 4.1.10 to get the Vagrantfile with the fix.

If the upgrade is not possible for you right now, copy the updated vagrant file for your project:
https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce-application/blob/4.1.10/Vagrantfile

Comment: Thanks Andrey, That was pretty useful. Got the local setup and vagrant working. Awesome.